# Transforming around cursor doesn't work

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, transforms

I'm having problem with vertex rotating. Rotating/scalling around cursor works fine in object mode, but in edit mode Blender rotates verticies around origin point instead. Rotating aroung bounding box also works fine. 
What's the problem? Have I clicked something? I'm using 2.79b.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got this. The reason was the object scale different from 1. I've applied the scale, and rotation works properly again. 
Isn't this some kind of bug?